# Spawn_model for gazebo.urdf files

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic, spawn-model, xacro, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to edit the file turtlebot3_world.launch that's code is the following in Melodic:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="x_pos" default="-1.0"/>
  <arg name="y_pos" default="-6"/>
  <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find multibot3)/worlds/turtlebot3_world.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

  <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_$(arg model) -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
</launch>
```

My question is this:
My understanding of this suggests to me that I need two files, a .urdf.xacro for the visual part and a .gazebo.xacro for the various sensors and plugin.
I want to modify this file to charge my definitions and not only that corresponding to turtlebot3, so based on my understanding (wrong I guess) I did this:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="x_pos" default="-2.0"/>
  <arg name="y_pos" default="-0.5"/>
  <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/turtlebot3_world.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

  <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-file /home/xyz/ros_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).gazebo.xacro -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
  
</launch>
```

But then I get this error:

```
spawn_model: error: argument -param: not allowed with argument -file
[spawn_urdf-4] process has died [pid 3277, exit code 2, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -file /home/xyz/ros_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle_pi.gazebo.xacro -x -2.0 -y -0.5 -z 0.0 -param robot_description __name:=spawn_urdf __log:=/home/xyz/.ros/log/e5538a02-69f2-11eb-82a4-40b89aaac2f7/spawn_urdf-4.log].
log file: /home/xyz/.ros/log/e5538a02-69f2-11eb-82a4-40b89aaac2f7/spawn_urdf-4*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371300/spawn_model-for-gazebo.urdf-files/) by [Giuseppe_](https://answers.ros.org/users/69393/giuseppe_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My understanding of this suggests to me that I need two files, a .urdf.xacro for the visual part and a .gazebo.xacro for the various sensors and plugin.

You are generally correct, but it's not strictly necessary to separate the files like that.  That is a convenient way to organize the information, but you can put it all in one file or several files if you want.  The [URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) are great for gaining a better understanding.  Here's [another one](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch#UsingroslaunchtoSpawnURDFRobots) from Gazebo.  One thing to note is that although the information may be in many separate files, there is one definition file that [includes references](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Including_other_xacro_files) to the others, so that's the only one you need in the launch file.

In the first launch file above, the definition is loaded from the URDF file (`$(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro`) to the `robot_description` parameter:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />
```

Then, the `-param` argument tells the `spawn_urdf` node to load the description from a parameter, in this case named `robot_description`.  The `-model` argument simply tells the node the name of the model--not what it contains.

People often use the parameter method because the description is useful elsewhere, like in RViz, but you can also load it directly to the `spawn_model` node, in which case you'd use the `-file` argument instead of the `-param` argument.  That brings us to your error:

```
spawn_model: error: argument -param: not allowed with argument -file
```

The issue is that you're telling the `spawn_urdf` node to look in two different places for the model.  You can only use one of these arguments at a time.  In your case, I recommend deleting the file part and just using the param part like the first launch file.  If the file loaded to `robot_description` contains or includes references to your changes, it should work.

###An Example
Let's say I wrote an entirely new description file, `my_robot.urdf.xacro`.  If I've divided the Gazebo parts into a separate file, I could include it with this line in `my_robot.urdf.xacro`:

```
<xacro:include filename="$(find my_pkg)/urdf/my_robot.gazebo.xacro" />
```

Then I could spawn that model with this launch file:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="x_pos" default="-1.0"/>
  <arg name="y_pos" default="-6"/>
  <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find multibot3)/worlds/turtlebot3_world.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

  # Note: the `--inorder` option is default as of Melodic, so it's not necessary.
  <param name="my_robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find my_pkg)/urdf/my_robot.urdf.xacro" />

  <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-urdf -model my_robot_name -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param my_robot_description" />
</launch>
```

I changed the `robot_description` parameter name to `my_robot_description` for illustrative purposes.  You can name the parameter whatever you want and reference it in the spawn node's arguments.  `robot_description` is pretty standard though, and some other code may look for it by default.

Hopefully, my rambling has helped, but feel free to ask for clarifications.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Giuseppe_](https://answers.ros.org/users/69393/giuseppe_/) on 2021-02-08**:
@tryan much thanks to your detailed explanation, I think you solved my problem, I'll let you know ;)
So I studied how it works xacro to understand better what you said